# Basic Django POST not creating model with sqlite

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

When I click the submit button, it redirects me to the create model (in this case create record) page, and does not actually create a new model, it doesn't appear in the main page which shows all models that were created.

I tried following this tutorial: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-s7e_Fy6NRU)

I feel like I did mostly the same things as him, and yet my form submission button does not create my post. The differences between our programs is simply the naming and the number of fields in my model.

The user registration form works, but that is using a function based view, this is using a class based view (should still work as far as I know), and there are barely any differences between the model creation html and the user registration html.

Here's the model creation form, *record_form.html*:

```
{% extends "catalog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1 class="text py-3 pt-4">Create a Record!</h1>
    <style>
    .text {
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #060007;
    }
    </style> 
    <div class="shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-light rounded">
        <form class="form" method="POST" action="/catalog/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                {{ form.name }}
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="description">Description:</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                {{ form.description }}
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="date_start">Date start:</label>
                {{ form.date_start }}
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="date_end">Date end:</label>
                {{ form.date_end }}
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer:</label>
                {{ form.manufacturer }}
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="condition_rating">Condition rating (between 0 and 5):</label>
                {{ form.condition_rating }}
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="condition_description">Condition description:</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                {{ form.condition_description }}
            </p>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="Create Record" value="Create Record" class="submit action-button">
            </div>
        </form>
        <style>
            .form {
                color: #060007;
            }
        </style>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Here's my models that the program is using in *models.py*:

```
class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # not necessary as django adds this to every model, but declared so that it is clear
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter name')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='Enter description')
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-last_modified', 'name'] # '-' reverses order, e.i. newest first
        # ordering = ['name','-last_modified'] # '-' reverses order, e.i. newest first
    

class Catalog(CommonInfo):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('catalog-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Record(CommonInfo):
    my_catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Many records to one Catalog. Deletes all records associated with deleted catalog.
    date_start = models.DateField() # TODO - is date range for when aquired or creation? 
    date_end   = models.DateField()

    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)

    condition_rating =  DecimalField( 
        help_text='Enter condition rating from 0 to 5',
        default=0, 
        decimal_places=2, 
        max_digits=3, 
        validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0')), MaxValueValidator(Decimal('5'))]
    )
    condition_description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='Enter condition description')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('record-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} ({self.my_catalog})'
```

Here's the CreateView class in *views.py*:

```
class RecordCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Record
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'manufacturer', 'condition_rating', 'condition_description'] #Owner/nation/continent not able to be done, since provenance is not linked to Record
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here's *urls.py*:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import RecordDetailView, RecordCreateView
from . import views
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', views.about, name='catalog-about'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='catalog-home'),
    path('catalog/', views.catalogList, name='catalog-list'),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='about/', permanent=True)),
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name='catalog-login'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name='catalog-logout'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='catalog-register'),
    path('record/<int:pk>/', RecordDetailView.as_view(), name='record-detail'),
    path('record/new/', RecordCreateView.as_view(), name='record-create'),
]
```

Comment: can you share the `urls.py` file too.

Comment: @Shanks I've updated the post to include urls.py, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

i dont see a field "name" on Recored table and you don't give the catalog on your RecordCreateView.

Comment: "name" is in the CommonInfo class, which is given to the Record class as a parameter (as far as I'm aware). I'm not sure what you mean by "you don't give the catalog...", am I supposed to? Catalog shouldn't be necessary to create a record.